# How do I prevent a child div from overflowing beyond the height of the parent div?

Tags: css, html, positioning

On the page I'm laying out, there's a bunch of divs stuffed into each other. The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<div id="overlay">
<div id="main_section">
  <div class="left">yadda yadda left sidebar</div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div id="header">yadda yadda header</div>
    <div id="main_content"><img class="resize content" src="static/some_image.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">yadda yadda right sidebar</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The main container is overlay, and it used fixed position, like so:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 90%;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

(I'm layering multiple backgrounds with various levels of opacity, which is why there is main_section, overlay, etc.)

Now, all the children use relative positioning, which works out fairly well. The problem occurs in #main_content. #main_section and .middle both have height: 100%, and as expected they go all the way down to the bottom of #overlay. Now, here's #main_content:

```
#main_content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: right;
}
```

This doesn't work as I want it to, since due to the image size the thing extends right down to the bottom of the page instead of to the bottom of #overlay.  I've tried overflow-y: scroll and height: inherit, I've tried max-height: 100%, and I am ripping my hair out. Stackoverflow is my last hope before I get a heart attack!

Comment: You should provide a working example of your issue...

Comment: Try mocking up this problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ and linking to it. This would help us see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed and added some properties since the full source code wasn't provided (colors only present to recognize relevant blocks). It appears to me that the mistake must be somewhere else in your CSS, because the underneath code works fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #overlay {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 90%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
        border: 2px solid green;
    }
    #main_section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: yellow;
    }
    .middle {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: lavender;
        position: relative;
    }
    #main_content {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 70%;
        text-align: right;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: red;
    }
    img {
        width: 700px;
        height: 2000px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="overlay">
<div id="main_section">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="middle">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="main_content"><img class="resize content" src="static/some_image.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="right"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The only time when I get the same problem as you, is when I set these `#main_content {position:fixed;}` or `.middle {position:fixed;}`. Are you sure `#main_content` or `.middle`didn't inherit a fixed position? Or maybe an unnoticed class added the property?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself having the same problem.

There are answers to quite similar questions on SO. But all I found was only working either on the whole page/body or with a fixed height on the container. Some use float and positioning (absolute or relative does not really matter here). The overall tenor however is to use `display` elements, which I find to be both the most elegant and practical.

Below is my solution. You can place it in any container. It will adopt exactly to the container height and width, no overflow. Well as you can see it just combines an `display: inline-block` parent with a `display: table` child.

Note that if you add a `display: table-caption` the overflow will occur again (please leave a comment if you know the reason for this).

```
<div id="#place_me_anywhere"
     style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table;height: 100%;width: 100%;">  
        <!--<div style="display: table-caption;">
            Height overflow will occur
        </div>-->
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;background-color: pink;height: 100%;">
            <!-- this row consumes all remaining height without overflow -->
            <div style="display: table-cell;width: 10em;min-width: 10em;background-color: red;">
                Just an example of some fixed width column/cell
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;background-color: blue;">
                takes the remaining width
            </div>
        </div>

   </div>

</div>
```